# Eclipse C++ std::vector methods invalid parameters errors

Tags: eclipse, c++11, android-ndk, stdvector, eclipse-cdt

I am working on an Android application that uses OpenCV 2.4.9 and NDKr9 as dependecies. I also use Eclipse 4.4 Luna as the IDE, with CDT plugin 8.4 installed.

Whenever I'm trying to use the methods std::vector.at(int), or the "[]" method, i get weird errors. For instance, consider the code:

```
#include <vector>
.........................

struct CustomStruct {
int level;
Point firstPoint, secondPoint, middlePoint;
};
.........................

int maxElemNr = 10;
std::vector<CustomStruct > customStructVector(maxElemNr);
.........................

for(int i=0;i<customStructVector.size();i++){
            if(customStructVector.at(i).level == 0){

            }
        }
```

At `customStructVector.at(i)` Eclipse tells me the following:

> Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: ResultWithEvidence & at(?) const
>   ResultWithEvidence & at(?)'

If I want to use the "[]" operator, instead of the "at(index)" method, i get the following:
`resultWithEvidenceVector[i].level` tells me that the field `level` is not found.

I am by no means an expert C/C++ coder, and I am rather new at working with the NDK. Coming from a Java background, I was expecting to get an object of type `CustomStruct` when calling either `customStructVector.at(i)` or `customStructVector[i]`, such that I could then simply access the field `level` on my object, to read its value.

Also, declaring my vector as

```
int maxElemNr = 10;
std::vector<CustomStruct> customStructVector;
customStructVector.reserve(maxElemNr);
```

I get:

> Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: void reserve(?) '

I have searched for answers, and came with the theory that eclipse might not use the c++11 version of the std library?

I've read about the vector class from [here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4027/C-Tutorial-A-Beginners-Guide-to-stdvector-Part-1.htm). Also, this issue closely resembles the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836213/android-ndk-opencv-invalid-arguments-for-substr).

Will provide more info about my environment and such, if needed. Would like to solve this, as it's quite a blocker for my project as of now..

What am I doing wrong? I had no problems compiling and running the code previously to using the `std::vector` class.

**LE:** apparently the workaround `&(resultWithEvidenceVector.data()+i)->level` is recognized by the editor, and the code compiles. Would still like to use the `std::vector` as it is supposed to be used though.

Comment: Eclipse is only so good. I get errors from the editor that do not exist. I would usually find that with simple templates it is fine, so your case seems a little extreme, but I do find that it gives me errors that are simply not there. Do a compile to find the truth of the matter then ignore or switch off the eclipse errors (not ideal).

Comment: I ended up using the classic c-style arrays...Thank you for your help!

Although I have bypassed this problem, if anyone knows the answer to it, please post it. Maybe someone else will have the same problem, might find your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. It works in Visual Studio compiler but when i try to access vector element i get exactly the same error.

However it seems that if you don't use 'at' then it works for example customStructVector.at(i) use customStructVector(i),

It is strange. I didn't test it in detail. Please note that if you have vector you have to cast the result in order to access the type members.

Regards